# Catkin unable to find package inside workspace

Tags: ros, catkin, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am rebuilding my workspace, my one package depend upon other. I deleted build and devel directories and tried to build again but it says "The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found"

Although package is in workspace. Any idea how to do that ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263381/catkin-unable-to-find-package-inside-workspace/) by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 377 on 2017-06-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-06-07**:
If package1 depends on package2, try this: `catkin_make --pkg package2` then `catkin_make` again. This will first build only package2, and then the entire workspace. It will mean that package2 is already built and can be found by catkin the second time.

**Comment by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) on 2017-06-08**:
Never delete your devel folder!

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2017-06-08**:
@gstavrinos why? it is generated. @tonyParker please include the whole error message and more details about your setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the answer.
The package on which my package depend upon is not ros/catkin package. So catkin unable to find it. For building such packages following catkin arguments needs to pass at the first time buidling of catkin workspace.

```
catkin_make --cmake-args -DUSE_CATKIN=ON
```

---

Originally posted by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) with karma: 377 on 2017-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1